# Is it safe to remove a sprite from its own class method with Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a derived sprite object and I wanted to remove this sprite when it has met a specific condition. Are there any issues deleting it with the format 'pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill()' from within the sprite class method itself?

```
class Pellet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, tank):
  ...
  def update(self):
    """Update the position of bullets."""
    self.rect.move_ip(self.xposc, self.yposc)
    if offEdges(self.rect):
      self.kill()
```

Comment: I've tried it with success, but I wanted to know if there were instances where it would create some issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to unequivocally delete the sprite, this should work, but there is two possible problems that could occur while trying to delete an object, depending on how you want to use it. If you call the object's functions only from groups, then this will get rid of it. If you call a function from a specific instance of the class, than it will keep getting called. This is why it is sometimes better to use groups in situations like this, even when there is only one member, as they handle all of this for you. If you want to delete the instance of the class, you could call

```
self.__del__()
```

but this could cause several problems, such as the fact that when you try to call anything from or on that variable, it will now be undefined. It is much better to have groups and use the kill() function. The other possible problem is of coarse, if you do not want to remove the sprite from all of the groups. If this is the case, you can just remove it individually from the various groups. For example, if it is a render updates group, you could do this:

```
<groupname>.remove(self)
```